# Vue.js - Watch data changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I added a Bootstrap Vue Table to my app and wanted to log when the user switches to another page using the built in pagination.

https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/

For this, I added a `@change` that is supposed to listen and log the v-model of the pagination, `currentPage`. However, it seems to be called before `currentPage` is actually updated.

How can I properly listen to this updating?

This is what I have tried:
https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/394424/

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   totalRows: 50,
   perPage: 10,
   currentPage: 1
  },
  methods: {
   pagination() {
     console.log(this.currentPage);
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <b-pagination :total-rows="totalRows" :per-page="perPage" v-model="currentPage" @change="pagination" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can watch `currentPage`

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   totalRows: 50,
   perPage: 10,
   currentPage: 1
  },
  watch: {
    currentPage: function (newVal) {
       console.log('Change to page', newVal)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setTo() {
     this.currentPage = 1;
     console.log(this.currentPage);
    }
  }
})
```

[Check demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/pt3jmbzh/)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Do you know by any chance if it is better to use `console.log(newVal)`, or to just use `console.log(this.currentPage)` within the function, performance wise? https://jsfiddle.net/Sirence/pt3jmbzh/3/

Comment: I think both ways will work. I prefer `console.log(newVal)`